# Need helt with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like some help with a query on a personal project that I can´t figure out by myself.
Im trying to summerize usedQuantity by the productId from three diffrent tables in one query.

**SQL result I would like:**

| productId | TOTAL usedQuantity |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 |
| 20 | 20 |
| 50 | 100 |
| 60 | 120 |

**Exempel data:**

**Table One:**

| Id | productId | usedQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | 20 |
| 3 | 50 | 50 |

**Table Two:**

| Id | productId | usedQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 60 | 60 |

**Table three:**

| Id | productId | usedQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 60 | 60 |

Comment: Why do you have three tables with the same fields?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Replace source tables data sample with their CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. We, for example, **must** see does `productId` column is defined as unique.

Answer (score 1):

seems you need the sum of the table's union

```
select productId, sum(usedQuantity) usedQuantity
from (
   select productId, usedQuantity
   from  table_one
   union all
   select productId, usedQuantity
   from  table_two
   union all
   select productId, usedQuantity
   from  table_three ) t
group by productId
```

Answer (score 0):

try below query, please..

```
    select t1.ProductId, Sum(isnull(t1.Quantity,0)+isnull(t2.Quantity,0)+isnull(t3.Quanity,0)) from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.ProductId=t2,ProductId left join table3 t3 on t1.ProductId=t3.ProductId
group by t1.ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [union all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) and [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get the [aggregated sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) of a column grouped:

Create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `usedQuantity` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`productId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `usedQuantity` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`productId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t3` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `usedQuantity` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`productId`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `t1` (`id`, `productId`, `usedQuantity`) VALUES
  ('1', '10', '10'),      ('2', '20', '20'),      ('3', '50', '50');
  
INSERT INTO `t2` (`id`, `productId`, `usedQuantity`) VALUES
  ('1', '10', '10'),      ('2', '60', '60');
  
INSERT INTO `t3` (`id`, `productId`, `usedQuantity`) VALUES
  ('1', '50', '50'),      ('3', '60', '60');
```

Query those table by building a `UNION ALL` of their values, then group by `productId` and sum up the `usedQuantity` column:

```
select productId, sum(usedQuantity)   # as ... if you like other column header
from (
  select * from t1   # replace * with your field-names to minimizes
  union all          # data retrieved and avoid problems if your table
  select * from t2   # definition change later - see remark by @Akina
  union all          
  select * from t3
) as t_all
group by productId
```

Result:

```
productId   sum(usedQuantity)
10          20 
20          20
50          100
60          120
```

Having three tables with exact same DDL seems odd to me, but this works.

- Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/098705/2/0
- Documentation links are to the 8.0 - fiddle is 5.6 - functions the same.

Comment: Perfect this will help me in my beer project :D Cheers!

Comment: @TobiasAxbard Do not use asterisks, specify separate column names... if the structure of some table will be altered in future (added or swapped columns) the query will fail. See **scaisEdge**'s answer.

Comment: @akina Agree - i was lazy in using asterics - the added disadvantage is that it populates the union with the id fields not used at all - dedicated field names would be better. Edited.